# Not feeling 100% about my Controller design

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, controller

Basically, I'm uploading an excel file and parsing the information then displaying what was parsed in a view.

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using QuimizaReportes.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;

namespace QuimizaReportes.Controllers
{
    public class UploadController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase excelFile)
        {
            if (excelFile != null)
            {
                //Save the uploaded file to the disc.
                string savedFileName = "~/UploadedExcelDocuments/" + excelFile.FileName;
                excelFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(savedFileName));

                //Create a connection string to access the Excel file using the ACE provider.
                //This is for Excel 2007. 2003 uses an older driver.
                var connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;", Server.MapPath(savedFileName));

                //Fill the dataset with information from the Hoja1 worksheet.
                var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Hoja1$]", connectionString);
                var ds = new DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(ds, "results");
                DataTable data = ds.Tables["results"];

                var people = new List<Person>();

                for (int i = 0; i < data.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    Person newPerson = new Person();
                    newPerson.Id = data.Rows[i].Field<double?>("Id");
                    newPerson.Name = data.Rows[i].Field<string>("Name");
                    newPerson.LastName = data.Rows[i].Field<string>("LastName");
                    newPerson.DateOfBirth = data.Rows[i].Field<DateTime?>("DateOfBirth");

                    people.Add(newPerson);
                }

                return View("UploadComplete", people);
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Error", "Upload");                      
        }

        public ActionResult Error()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Not feeling so confident this is the best approach. Any suggestion any of you MVC3 vets have for this aspiring senior programmer? :)

Should I call another Action, "UploadComplete" and have that callthe UploadComplete view instead of calling a View directly from the [POST]Index action? When do I know whether to use one approach or the other?

Comment: `OleDbDataAdapter`, `DataSet` and `DataTable`? In an MVC application? In a controller? Indeed, there are reasons to worry :-)

Comment: @Darin: Please elaborate. Half comments aren't really helpful.

Comment: He's saying that you shouldn't have data access in your controller

Comment: @Linkgoron: Where should I move the code then?

Comment: Search for data access logic and business layer seperation you should also search for object relational mappers, I'm writing from a cell phone so I cant elaborate but this will hopefully give you a few pointers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [Post-Redirect-Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern would perfectly apply here. You can pass "people" data using TempData for example.

Comment: Isn't that what I'm doing though? I'm POSTING the Action, then redirecting to a View. A GET View.

Comment: You don't redirect to UploadComplete, you just render it from your POST request. Given that, if user refreshes page the file would be uploaded twice.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably reduce the code in the Index action to simply saving the file, and redirect to another action that takes care of reading the data out of the file and displaying it.

RedirectToAction can be called with a third parameter for route values which could identify the file for reading.